# Is there an R function to run the same filter command on all of my columns?

Tags: r, loops, data-cleaning

I have an excel database with around 250 objects (names of different people), and I would like to know if there´s a function to perform the same command on all of my objects, I have been using the function grep() with each individual name, but i would like to obtain the urls for each individual name without having to do it manually, is there an easier way of doing it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ATLY.png)

```
`Alejandro Díaz Domínguez` [grep(".gob.mx", `Alejandro Díaz Domínguez`)] 

 
 [1] "http://www.csg.gob.mx                                        
 [2] "http://www.csg.gob.mx                                      
 [3] "https://sic.gob.mx
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please give us some context to your question. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints. It's a good start to give some data, make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and give an example of your desired output.

Comment: Also: in general, please include text-based examples (like your data frame example) as **text** rather than as screenshots; it's much more accessible that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pattern is ".gob.mx" for all columns and every column has a person, you may want to use `lapply()`.

```
lapply(your_dataframe, function(x) x[grep(".gob.mx", x)])
```